# CDI - Sessions Scope - New session scope for each request scope

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, cdi, session-scope

I have a @SessionScoped CDI bean  which is nicely storing information per user session. However I would like to use the same bean but have a new instance of it in say a request scope but once it gets created it remains in the session for that request. So for another request I want it to create a new bean.

Is this possible using CDI?

Comment: How would that work? When you `@Inject` that bean somewhere, which one should the implementation choose (since they're all named the same)? If you describe what you want to do with that bean people can offer better solutions.

Comment: I cannot comprehend what you are trying to do. Describe your functional requirement. If you want to reuse a bean implementation then extend from it and use a @Qualifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a new @RequestScoped bean that creates your existing bean class via the normal new operator (i.e. not injected).  You can't simultaneously treat a single bean obtained by the container as request and session scoped.